# Cordova is undefined After loading file:///android_assets/file.html

Tags: javascript, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser, ionic-native

after loading file.html with inappbrowser
i have a script tag which calls default_protocol_main.js file

In Default_protocol_main.js everything is working fine except

alert(cordova.version);

Answer (score 0):

not able to understand what are you trying to convey please provide the source code the way you are using the code then it may be possible

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nandi.development